# getting marker in current location

Tags: android, android-maps, android-location

I'm a biggener with android app and i'm interested in GeoLocalisation app.
so, I developed an application that returns the current location of the user device (Latitude/longitude) and my problem is that I want to get a marker in that location.
you can find my source code in this link so please i'l someone knows how to solve this problem i'm gonna be greatfull
http://hotfile.com/dl/134520763/75c0f91/current_location.rar.html

Answer (score 1):

class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {
        private ArrayList mOverlays = new ArrayList();
        private Context mContext;

```
    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
        dialog.show();
        return true;
    }
}



GeoPoint    geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6), (int) (longitude * 1E6));

        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
        itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
overlayItem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Starting Location", "any text");
                                    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
                        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

            MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
            mapController.animateTo(geoPoint);
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but unfortunately, as i'm not familiar with android applications I found some problems integrating this code with mine so please can you please help me do it.

Comment: thank you so much, I will try to run this updated source code, it brings me some errors but i'll try to fix it.

Comment: hello,
I finally managed to solve the error of the code above but when launching the application, it shows the MapView with a random position (no marker) and even the introduction of latitude and longitude from the GPS does not change position
link to download the new code :
http://hotfile.com/dl/135975357/b7474c5/current_location.rar.html

Comment: in the logCat I have this error :
MapActivity : couldn't get connection factory client

Answer (score 0):

Post you code inline. You will need to use something like ItemizedOverLay. Look [Here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html)